# Jquery GoogleMaps Api onclick show

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps-api-3, responsive-design

I'm trying to hide and show the googlemaps api onclick but it doesn't seem to be working. 
If I remove this code:

```
$('#map-canvas').hide();

$('#left p').click(function() {
    $('#map-canvas').show();
});
```

it works fine. But if I add this then it only shows a portion of the map. And also, when I resize, it doesn't seem to keep it centered on the latlong assigned.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alga/Mcjg5/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to reinitialize your map like this:

```
$('#map-canvas').hide();
  $('#left p').click(function(){
       $('#map-canvas').show();
       initialize();
  });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mcjg5/5/)